# Cant fetch users posts , says technical error occur

Tags: java, string

when the app is run and the user tries to fetch their posts, a technical error text display is shown, a user is supposed to post a picture or text and then later view them

cant move way forward

```
private void getPosts() {
        refreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.default_item).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Posts")
                .whereEqualTo("userId",FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {

                        if(!querySnapshot.isEmpty()){

                            for(DocumentChange doc:querySnapshot.getDocumentChanges()){
                                Post post = doc.getDocument().toObject(Post.class).withId(doc.getDocument().getId());
                                postList.add(post);
                                mAdapter_v19.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                            }

                            if(postList.isEmpty()){
                                refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                                rootView.findViewById(R.id.default_item).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }

                        }else{
                            refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                            rootView.findViewById(R.id.default_item).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        Toasty.error(rootView.getContext(), "Some technical error occurred", Toasty.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
                        Log.e("Error",e.getMessage());
                    }
                });

    }

}
```

Comment: Error 404: Question not found. Also, we're gonna need to see the error.

Comment: its supposed to show the user posts but instead it posts an error, i want it to show the posts and bypass the technical error issue, just look carefully please maybe i missed something